# Given Gain function, how to design a causal, stable and minimum phase IIR filter?

Tags: filter-design, lowpass-filter, infinite-impulse-response, hilbert-transform, minimum-phase

I am given $|H(\omega)|$, I wonder if minimum phase stable causal filter is unique and how to calculate it.

Comment: if you're wanting to design a finite-order IIR (determine the order $N$ and the $2N+1$ coefficients, you have to use something like the [Prony method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prony%27s_method) or [Greg Berchin's FDLS](http://www2.units.it/ramponi/teaching/DSP/materiale/ES_5_2.m).

Comment: @robertbristow-johnson: Prony's method designs an IIR filter given a prescribed impulse response. How would you use it here when the magnitude of the frequency response is given?

Comment: @MattL., i guess i would first create a minimum-phase complex frequency response, and compute an impulse response from that.  or use Greg's FDLS, since it's frequency domain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $H(\omega)=e^{\alpha(\omega)+j\phi(\omega)}$ is a minimum phase frequency response, then the attenuation $\alpha(\omega)$ and the phase $\phi(\omega)$ are related by the following [Hilbert transform](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert_transform) relationship:

$$\phi(\omega)=-\frac{1}{\pi}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{\alpha(\Omega)}{\omega-\Omega}d\Omega$$

So $\phi(\omega)$ is uniquely determined by $\alpha(\omega)$. [This](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimum_phase#Relationship_of_magnitude_response_to_phase_response) is the corresponding wikipedia entry.

Comment: @user40129: I just looked around but couldn't find anything convincing. In 'The Fourier Integral and Its Applications' by Papoulis there's proof of a similar relationship using contour integration. And in Oppenheim and Schafer's book (Discrete-Time Signal Processing) there's something like a proof of the equivalent relationship for discrete-time systems, but part of it is left as a 'problem'.

Comment: Proof is at Page 206 of  'The Fourier Integral and Its Applications' by Papoulis. Thanks!